# As3 and FlashVars

Tags: actionscript-3

Im stuck

I got this flash that need's to be configured in a certain way

My code looks like this

HTML

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="banner.swf" width="896" height="240">
    <param name="movie" value="banner.swf" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="hrefUrl=http://stackoverflow.com&popup=true" /> 
</object>
```

Actionscript

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.display.LoaderInfo;

//var paramList:Object = root.loaderInfo.parameters;
//var flashVars:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;

// Url to page, default to google
var hrefUrl:String = (root.loaderInfo.parameters.hrefUrl) ? root.loaderInfo.parameters.hrefUrl : "http://www.google.com";

// Popup or not, default to _self
var popup:String = (root.loaderInfo.parameters.popup == "true") ? "_blank" : "_self";

// Fire the event
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(hrefUrl), popup);
}
```

For some reason this doesn't work but if I for some reason put the flashvars in the data parameter it works

Example

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="banner.swf?hrefUrl=http://stackoverflow.com&popup=true" width="896" height="240">
```

What could be wrong here? I've starred myself blind on this one

Thanks

Comment: may be `root` not targeting `[object MainTimeline]`. Did u tried stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be `root` is not targeting  `[object MainTimeline]`. So go with `stage`.

Answer (score 2):

`root.loaderInfo...` will work if the actionscript you have shown us is in the main timeline. Otherwise, use `stage.loaderInfo...`